# Descending ListNode Iterator Implementation

Tags: java, linked-list, deque

My goal in this method is to write the implementation for an iterator that iterates through elements of a listNode in descending order. (From the back to the front) I have attached my implementation of the ascending iterator. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
 public MyDescendingDequeIterator(ListNode<E> back, ListNode<E> front) {                    
  frontOfList = front;
  nextToReturn = back;
   while (nextToReturn.next != null) {
    nextToReturn = nextToReturn.next;
}          
}


public boolean hasNext() {
 if (nextToReturn == null){
 return false;
 } else {
 ListNode<E> current = frontOfList;
 return true;
 }
}

public E next() {
ListNode<E> current = frontOfList;
while ( current.next != nextToReturn ) {
  current = current.next;
}
nextToReturn = current;

return nextToReturn.data;

}
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided it's a regular ListNode implementation that has only next() method, you'll need to implement the prev() method - the hasNext in that case is quite similar to the one you've implemented already.

The other approach is to hold the start of the list and to iterate each time until next element will be nextToReturn (and then update nextToReturn). This is less desired approach since you'll need to iterate O(m^2) from end to start of list of length m;

UPDATE:

OK, first of all you don't need number of elements, since it's quite opposite to the Iterator idea.

So let's say we have

```
public MyDescendingDequeIterator(ListNode<E> back, ListNode<E> front) {                    
  frontOfList = front;
  nextToReturn = frontOfList;
  current = frontOfList;
}
```

Next thing is than you want to set the `nextToReturn = back` (now you don't use `back` at all). And you don't really need two variables, since `nextToReturn` is the current iterator.

So it transforms to:

```
public MyDescendingDequeIterator(ListNode<E> back, ListNode<E> front) {                    
      frontOfList = front;
      nextToReturn = back;
    }
```

Now let's look on the `next()` method

As I said you don't need an indexed `for` here, since you've got frontOfList that has a next attribute.

So it could be:

```
public E next() {
    ListNode<E> current = frontOfList;
    while ( current.next != nextToReturn ) {
      current = current.next;
    }
    nextToReturn = current;

    return nextToReturn.data;

}
```

`hasNext` implementation should be straightforward from here. Just pay attention that according to the good coding standards the method that starts with `is` or `has` rarely changes the state of the object.

Note, that I also omit possible null checks here and other possible specific checks as is just an example of direction.

UPDATE 2:

As I think of it now, you don't need the second parameter in the constructor either, just this:

```
public MyDescendingDequeIterator(ListNode<E> front) {                    
    frontOfList = front;      
    nextToReturn = front;

    // calculate back here instead of get it as param
    while ( nextToReturn.next != null) {
        nextToReturn = nextToReturn.next;
    }          
}
```

UPDATE 3:

Look, it won't help to just start writing some code and expect it to work, you should sit down first and start drawing the boxes with the arrows on the piece of paper and then try to understand what each function should do.

As I said before, your `hasNext()` method has a bug and incorrect in general. Why do you check the null? You move from back to front, do you have a null at some place at the front? What do you need the `current` object for. What does it do?

The `next()` method should check also if you're already at the first element. Otherwise it will (and it does ) cause NullPointerException at the last element.

Try to debug first, or at least add some printouts, it helps to understand where the bug is. But first you should build the algorythm, **only then** start coding it, not vice versa.

Comment: I understand that I could iterate over the start of the list until I receive the element that is indexed one less than the value iterated the previous time. I am just unaware of how I can access a private field I declared in another class "front" which holds the node for the front of my LinkedList

Comment: Add a method setFront to MyDescendingDequeIterator, for example and call after it was created?

Comment: Or change a constructor to get two params, front and back - that's effectively the same, but with a couple of lines less.

Comment: Can I add a param for the front element in the following header? `public MyDescendingDequeIterator(ListNode<E> back)`

Comment: Yes, this is the constructor. Just add it as a second param.

Comment: Ive successfully returned the last value of the linked list, my problem now is that the value is being stored as _current_ and if I try to update _current_ to be the front of my list, it will run me an infinite loop....

Comment: I don't quite follow, why do you update *current* to *front*. Could you please post  the problematic code.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I notice that this works, but it only returns the last value of the linked list. The next() method needs to iterate the list from the back to front. My output here seems only to be the back of the list, but every time next is called, I need it to decrement the current.data to the previous node without using the previous() method..

Comment: It shouldy work exactly this way. Post your code please

Comment: Actually, no it is running fine, the only problem is now it is skipping the last element of the list. It is returning everytihng correctly but the back of the list

Comment: Why do you check the null in hasNext? First element will never be null. Also add check in next if you're already at the first element

Comment: I keep getting a null pointer exception.. Ill revise my code one sec.

Comment: I have revised my code to my most current script. I am super frustrated with this method, I am getting a nullPointerException as well as the iteration skipping the first element.